# TriangleFan Overrides everything else in OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

So I have drawn two triangles on my OnRenderFrame function. This works perfectly as I want it to be from my given sets of vertices.

```
            ///for outer two triangles that are blue
            GL.Uniform4(uniformLocations, 0.078f, 0.114f, 0.420f, 1.0f);
            GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 3); 
            GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 3, 3); 

            ///for inner two triangles that are crimson
            GL.Uniform4(uniformLocations, 0.8627f, 0.0784f, 0.2353f, 1.0f);
            GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 6, 3);
            GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 9, 3);
```

Now I want to add a circle at the centroid of one of the triangles. For this I used TriangleFan as follows:

```
            GL.Uniform4(uniformLocations, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // black for testing -- must be white

            int circleSides = 20; // number of sides of the circle polygon
            float[] circleVertices = new float[circleSides * 3];

            float centerX = 0.167f;
            float centerY = -0.217f;
            float radius = 0.05f;

            float angleIncrement = (float)(2.0f * Math.PI / circleSides);
            float currentAngle = 0.0f;

            for (int i = 0; i < circleSides; i++)
            {
                float x = centerX + (float)(radius * Math.Cos(currentAngle));
                float y = centerY + (float)(radius * Math.Sin(currentAngle));
                circleVertices[i * 3] = x;
                circleVertices[i * 3 + 1] = y;
                circleVertices[i * 3 + 2] = 0.0f;
                currentAngle += angleIncrement;
            }

            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, circleVertices.Length * sizeof(float), circleVertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.TriangleFan, 0, circleSides);
```

But this circle seems to overwrite my previous triangles. Is there a fix for this?

I am really new to OpenGL and am drawing using only vertices for now.

Note: My final aim is to draw a flag of Nepal(its a unique flag with two triangles)

Edit: I also tested drawing the triangles after the circle. When I do that I see a little hint of crimson at the edge of the circle. But everything else is white and my triangles are gone :/

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. Are you searching for [Depth Testing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test)

Comment: But I think I might have found the problem. I created a new buffer while drawing the circle so all my previous buffers were gone.